# Streaming Video on Azure using HTML 5 Player and Asp.net MVC4

Tags: html, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, streaming

I have a Asp.Net MVC 4 Webpage. I want to use HTML5 to play stream video with mp4 type. 
My video on Windows Azure with Media Service.

I deep searching on google about the HTML5 play stream video but not have the answer right,

Everyone can suggest me any code for Play Stream Video from Azure with HTML 5.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You best bet is to use Windows Azure Media Services.

You should transcode and publish your video from there.  Use a standard HTML5 video element with the URL that publishing gives you.

You need to set video autoplay off and enable buffering. If you're stuck I would suggest previewing the video from media services and hitting View Source and getting your HTML that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format as MPEG DASH to get it to smoothstream the MP4 file to the HTML5 video player. This is done by adding a format parameter to the manifest URL, as follows:

http://testendpoint-testaccount.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/fecebb23-46f6-490d-8b70-203e86b0df58/BigBuckBunny.ism/Manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)

Note the **(format=mpd-time-csf)** at the end of the URL.

I struggled to find this, too, so quite happy I finally found it. Here's the source URL from Microsoft:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-deliver-content-overview/